# Can access phpmyadmin from the internet but when I log in it says everything is logged in via localhost and not remotely

Tags: phpmyadmin

So I am having an issue with phpmyadmin to where when I login remotely, I am able to get in and do anything/everything I should be able to. The issue is that according to phpmyadmin, I don't have ssl enabled and that I'm accessing the site from the localhost and not from a remote machine. Is it because I have phpmyadmin running through IIS 10 and those don't work together very well? Or did I do some kind of configuration wrong? To give an idea, instead of saying I am connecting from *username*@192.168.1.1 or *usename*/192.168.1.1 it says I'm connected by *username*@localhost.[image]

Any help would be nice, other than that, I have stuff locked down as it should be, this is the one thing that is really confusing me though. And yes I am using SSL to the website, just wont show it there like I said. In the end I feel as though its a limitation of IIS 10 and not so much phpmyadmin.

I do wish to add that I access phpmyadmin from the main domain I use to access my website by just going to the subfolder in the link such as "google.com/phpmyadmin" then it takes me to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

That connection information is how MySQL sees the connection. When you connect from the webserver to the database server, that connection is occurring locally and not using encryption. Since the webserver is the machine connecting to MySQL, the connection information shown there reflects coming from a localhost connection rather than your client machine, since *to MySQL* it is a local connection.

The other half of the connection, between your web browser and the web server, is not shown in that section of the phpMyAdmin window.

There's nothing wrong with your installation or configuration, it's just that you're expecting to see information about the connection between the webserver and web browser but that window is showing you the connection between the database server and web server.